# can we create common onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) in a class in android for different activity

Tags: java, android, menu

Note:
Class ProcessingOptionMenu will be without its own layout.
Can a class without layout start another activity like below
class ProcessingOptionMenu starts new activity SettingABC

Activity A {
              ..

```
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.second_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        ProcessingOptionMenu objectMenu= new ProcessingOptionMenu();
        boolean resultReturn=objectMenu.identifyItem(item);
       }
                ..
}

Activity B {
               ..

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.second_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        ProcessingOptionMenu objectMenu= new ProcessingOptionMenu();
        boolean resultReturn=objectMenu.identifyItem(item);
       }
             ..
}


class ProcessingOptionMenu extends Activity {
    public boolean identifyItem(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.settingapp) {
        Intent intentAppSetting = new Intent(ProcessingOptionMenu.this,                        SettingABC.class);
            startActivity(intentAppSetting);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need a class that extends from Activity? Just write a method to handle the click event and fire a new activity therein. If you want you can put this method in a parent class and let your activities A and B extend from it.

Comment: I want to separate logic part from all activites

Comment: Then you can have a separate class, pass a Context to it, and later you can use the passed-in Context to start new activities. Still no need to extending from Activity.